# INSERT on multiple tables if condition PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I need to perform the following action:

My client consists in a big form that will be filled with personal data, plus an order that will be a random or a specific one. It’s only one form, so only one call.
And my DB looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE clients(
    clients_id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    full_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    street VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,

    random_order_id BIGINT REFERENCES random_order (id),
    specific_order_id BIGINT REFERENCES specific_order (id),
    
);

CREATE TABLE random_order(
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    amount NUMERIC(15),
    color VARCHAR(15)
);

CREATE TABLE specific_order(
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    brand VARCHAR(15),
    model VARCHAR(15)
);
```

What I am trying to do is, again with only one query, INSERT the personal data (will always be there, its mandatory), plus one or the another table depending on if the client decided to buy a random or specific item.
I was trying to send everything at once but of course this is not the way.

```
app.post("/clients", async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const results = await pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO clients (full_name, street ) VALUES($1, $2,)",
      [
        req.body.full_name,
        req.body.street
      ],
       "INSERT INTO random_order (amount, color) VALUES($1, $2)",
       [
         req.body.amount,
         req.body.color,

       ],
       "INSERT INTO specific_order (brand, model) VALUES ($1, $2)",
       [
         req.body.brand,
         req.body.model,
         
       ]
    );

    res.json();

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
});
```

Is this possible to perform?

Comment: What is `pool.query`, what library are you using?

Comment: "*with only one query*" - why? Are you referring to a http query or a database query?

Comment: Just use a transaction with 3 INSERT queries.

Comment: I don't follow how could I perform what I want with a transaction here

Comment: The biggest issue I see is you have your Foreign Key(FK) reference in the wrong direction.  Move the FK to the order tables and have them refer back to the client table. Then in the form you INSERT/UPDATE the client, grab the clients_id and then use that when INSERTing the specific  or random order.  Even if you stick with your current setup you would need to create the order first to get the id for the FK relationship in the client table.

Comment: Thank you @AdrianKlaver, I think its a good suggestion, even though what I am having problems with is not on the DB structure (that could be better or worse), but with how I implement on the server this multiple INSERTs at once.

Comment: I  am not familiar with `express/node.js` so I can't provide a detailed answer. The general process as @Bergi mentioned is to do the queries in a single transaction like this: 1) `BEGIN;` 2- 4) Run each `INSERT` query separately  5) `COMMIT;` or `ROLLBACK;` on error. This ensures that all the queries succeed and you move on or they all rollback and you start over.

Comment: @GuillerminaMartinez What is the problem you're trying to solve by doing them "at once"?

Comment: The request comes from the client in just one huge form with around 30 fields. I need to devide that request into different tables and insert them as they come.